# connecting web page to facebook page

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Ok, this is frustrating, I'm running in cricles, therefore I appreciate any hints or directions..

Having a web page, I need to have a share & like buttons on it. The SDK needs na APP ID to connect, so I've created an facebook page. Well, turns out page ID isn't the same as app ID. So, **having right now a web page, a FB page and a FB app, how do I connect these all together?**

I had tried to google how to "connect FB app to FB page". That only directed me to something about "Page Tab" at which point I found myself completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need a Page, you only need an App. Here´s where you can create one: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

After creating the App, you will see the App ID.

Comment: well, but having an app AND a page, how to connect these?

Comment: why do you want to connect them? you can add an app as a page tab, you can read insights from a page with an app, you can post to the page with an app....there are many different possibilities, depending on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Fair point.. two main things: (1) I probably desire FB page to share "likes" with web page, that is that hitting like on the web will propagate to the FB page. And the button on web page will show the same likes count as the FB page. (2) on the web having a share button. I know this doesn't require anything special, so, is there any possibility to see on FB page who shared anything from the web page?

Comment: (1) just use the facebook page url in the like button plugin. (2) no, what for do you want to know who shared something anyway?

Comment: (1) true, (2) no idea - you made me realize that I should have this conversation with the other person. So in the end, thank you very much for your patience, I think my question was answered. It is hard for me to grasp all those concepts of an app, a page, ... and put them all together.